# Wildfly server 10 Memory leak on deployment or undeployment

Tags: wildfly-10, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am using wildfly server 10 as well as wildfly server 17. I am facing the memory leak issue multiple times when I am deploying and undeploying the applications.

My server is install on Ubuntu 18.04 with 4 GB Memory / 80 GB Disk / BLR1 - Ubuntu 18.04 (LTS) x64 configuration.

Whenever I deploy my application war file 2/3 time I am getting this error. After restarting the wildfly server I am able to deploy or ready for deployment or my war file deployed successfully on server.

Hence I want to know why I am facing this type of issue if I have a better configuration?
How can fix this?
How can I avoid this type of issue?
Is wildfly server updation is the solution then Why I am facing the same issue in wildfly server 17?

Thank Prasad.

Comment: You'd need to profile to see what is happening. Do you have a bunch of startup EJB's or is the deployment quite large?

Comment: Could you please post the error log?

Comment: its working now